# Python not getting text between html tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, lxml

It looks like python has trouble finding text when it's marked with display=none, what should I do to overcome this issue?

Here's my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.domcop.com/domains/great-expired-domains/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
data = soup.find('div', {'id':'all-domains'})
data.text
```

the code returns []

I also tried with xpath:

```
from lxml import etree

data = etree.HTML(r.text)
anchor = data.xpath('//div[@id="all-domains"]/text()')
```

It returns the same thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the element with `id="all-domains"` is empty because it is either dynamically set by the javascript executed in the browser. With `requests` you only get the initial HTML page without the "dynamic" part, so to say. To get all domains, I'd just iterate over the table rows and extract the domain link texts. Working sample:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.domcop.com/domains/great-expired-domains/',
                 headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.97 Safari/537.36"})

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
for domain in soup.select("tbody#domcop-table-body tr td a.domain-link"):
    print(domain.get_text())
```

Prints:

```
u2tourfans.com
tvadsview.com
gfanatic.com
blucigs.com
...
twply.com
sweethomeparis.com
vvchart.com
```

Comment: Alright, thanks for that! Is there any other library for python that could read this text?

Comment: @Charles do you mean the text in the `all-domains` element? If you still need that, look into browser automation via `selenium`. But, I think you can go with the solution provided in the answer.

Comment: Your solution will do it in this case I was just wondering. Shouldn't Selenium only work for visible objects since it's literally like browing the web?

Comment: @Charles you can still get the text of invisible elements with `selenium`. You would not be able to interact with this element - click, mouse move etc, but since you just need the text - it is okay.